# Why does from read_data import get_minibatch() return ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'read_data'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently going through the book Fundamentals of Deep Learning by Nikhil Buduma and it appears there's an error in one of the scripts it provides. The script is meant to provide an introduction into sessions in Tensorflow and is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from read_data import get_minibatch

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="x", shape=[None, 784])
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([784,10], -1, 1), name = "w")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeroes([10]), name = "biases")
output = tf.matmul(x,w) + b

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
feed_dict = {"x" : get_minibatch()}
sess.run(output, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

The problem I'm having is that I receive the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'read_data'. The original script also had empty parenthesis after line 2's get_minibatch but I removed them to remove a different error. Do I have to externally download this library or something?

Comment: It means it can't find a module (either in your code folder or installed as a package). I'd look through the book and see if you're supposed to install something or maybe have created the `read_data.py` yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/darksigma/Fundamentals-of-Deep-Learning-Book/issues/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran across this same problem, reading the book.

read_data isn't any sort standard python library.

As Nick T said, it sort of seems like it ought to be a function that comes with the example source code for the book.

If you look at the example code on github, there are a few examples of reading data that are almost similar but not quite exact.

Anyway, i think the point is just that get_minibatch would be the function that feeds input data to the session.

I suspect the author didn't really intend us to run these examples verbatim.... or at least didn't test his examples really worked after writing them.  (This is the second example that didn't run for me).

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug in the script provided in the book:

Read more here: http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=0636920039709

Comment: I did see this already, but I guess I was hoping there was a solution out there. Thanks.